# Collective nouns affecting articles

Tags: articles, collective-nouns

I've noticed that the nouns that go after a collective noun often have either "a"/"zero" article even when the logic suggests using "the".
(I'm using the term "zero/a" because "zero" and "a" are very similar in meaning)

> When I was at that restaurant I was approached by a **group of _
> waiters**
>
> I was at the lecture but I noticed that  **a lot of _ students**
> weren't listening

Despite "waiters" being expected in this context (as well as students). We use "zero" instead of "the". I think that's because collective nouns often force us to emphasize the class of the object we're talking about, thus making us opt for "a/zero" (since only "a/zero" has this classifying function)

To test this hypothesis I want ask you to look at the following sentence:

> I started watching this TV series a few days ago and my friend told me
> that
> **the majority of **?** characters** will die by the end of season 1.

Should I say "the characters"? They are obviously expected to be present in a TV series, however, being used after a collective noun "the majority of" might force us to use "zero/a"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I was at that restaurant I was approached by a group of _ waiters

We don't use "the" because we're specifying the content of the group *in general* --waiters, as opposed to customers or food inspectors-- and not specifying that it was a group formed from a subset of *the* waiters from that restaurant. The listener is left to *infer* that the waiters in the group were some or all of *the* waiters working in that restaurant.

So your analysis is correct, that without "the", the preposition "of" specifies the *class* of the content of the group rather than the *specific source* of the content of the group.

If we say, "...a group of **the** waiters", then we probably should have mentioned the waiters in the context before.

This means that yes:

> ... the majority of **the** characters will die by the end of season 1

because we're specifying that the content of "majority" is specifically a subset of the characters on that show, rather than characters in general.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of **the characters** in the series will die by the end of Season One. [specific, that series]

The majority **of the people** on the bus were very hostile. [specific, that bus]

COMPARE:

The majority **of characters** in TV series are one-dimensional people. [a generality, TV series meant in the plural].

The majority **of people** on buses are rather patient. [generality, on buses]

English is quite tricky but one thing is pretty certain. "x of the y" is specific whereas "x of y plural noun" is a generality.

Comment: Similarly, 'a lot of **the students** [present at the lecture].